# Background that should be transparent is white

Tags: android, css, cordova, sass, ionic2

I'm making an app that uses the plugin cordova-plugin-camera-preview which let's you see the camera directly in the app.

To get started I took the tutorial from http://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-go-create-a-pokemon-go-style-interface-in-ionic-2/, the problem is that I can't see the camera because the transparent background is white.

In the tutorial there's a refresh button implemented which does activates this function:

```
refresh() {
    console.log('refreshing!');
    window['location'].reload();
}
```

When I click the button I can see the camera, but not the buttons or the navbar, just the camera content. After a second or so, the camera dissapears and I see the buttons, the navbar and the white background again and DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER, (some number), ms appears in the log.

This is my app.scss file, which should make the background transparent.

```
@import "../pages/home/home";

html, body, ion-content, ion-page, .nav-decor {
    background-color:transparent !important;;
}
```

Another thing to point out is that I'm running this on an Android phone attached to the computer using Ionic version 2.1.0.

Comment: What version of ionic are you using? The tutorial is not using a RC, so classes may vary.